# Is there a way to take a variable from one html file and use it in another

Tags: html

I have this code which takes the name into the "nm" variable

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}Search Page{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<form action="#" method="post">
    <p>User or Group:</p>
    <p><input type="text" name="nm"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
    
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to put this variable into a different html file which will show different things.
Can anyone suggest me the most efficient way to make this happen?

Comment: I see you are using django. You could send it back to the backend and then send that to whatever other template you want to send it to (via `context`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Django, send the `nm` text field back to your view in `views.py`, where you should access that variable (`nm = request.POST.get("nm")`) and then send that via the `context` variable in the `render()` function to your other HTML file (`return render(request, "your_other_file.html", {"nm": nm})`), where you can access the variable via interpolation (`{{ nm }}`)

Comment: thanks man, it was working for me now

Comment: @AadishShele Please upvote the answer and accept it as solution to let other people know that your question has been answered and as a thanks